# How to Set API endpoint for PCF Dev

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I have [installed](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/install-linux.html) PCF Dev in Linux machine. I need to find what will be the API endpoint and how to configure it.  
Also need to understand if there will be any GUI available for PCF Dev, and how can I configure it

Answer (score 1):

I believe the API URL should get printed at the end, when PCFDev starts, but in case you don't see it or that's changed it should be `https://api.local.pcfdev.io`.

See the docs here -> https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/usage.html#pcf-dev